# Role of Capacitors with additional power regulator

Tags: low-power

I have a a 7805 voltage regulator that has a capacitor on input and output.  The 5v from that regulator is then elsewhere in the circuit stepped down to 3.3v with another regulator.  I am wondering if i then NEED a capacitor on the input of the 3.3v regulator?
Am i misunderstanding the effect and purpose of the capacitors in this situation or do i always need capacitors on the input and output regardless of the situation.

thanks.

Comment: How far away are the regulators from one another?

Comment: Also, what is the expected load current? Will it vary?

Comment: the regulators are about 7cm apart.  the 5v provides power to a raspberry pi in addition to that 3.3v regulator.  On the 3.3v side of things are 2 RF trancievers that are rated thusly : 115mA when transmitting.  45mA when receiving.

Comment: i should add that from what i gather each tranciever cant send and receive at the same time.  However in my project both trancievers operate independently.  i.e. both could be sending at the same time etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that if the output of the 3.3V regulator is adequately bypassed that it could well *appear* to function without the capacitor (definitely follow the recommendations of the 3.3V regulator- a 7805 is a not a low impedance source at high frequencies).

Even if it seems to work and you think the datasheet does not prescribe a value, I would still recommend putting capacitor in there - something like a 1uF ceramic capacitor takes almost no space and costs next to nothing (less than a penny). There may be subtle (or not so subtle) instability effects that only manifest during rapid changes in load or at temperature extremes or with some instances of parts vs others and a simple test regime may not identify the latent issues. It may also reduce unintentional emissions by reducing the effective loop area.